# Apache-tomcat 6.0.39 webapps class loader vs JVM classpath

Tags: tomcat, classpath, classloader

I have a web application coupled to a services framework. The framework starts like any Java application and at the end of the boot sequence, it starts catalina tomcat in the same JVM.
I use JVM 7 and Tomcat 6.0.39.

I created a new service that should reuse from an existing one that have "view" , "model" and "controlle". For the webapps part, I use struts.

At start, the new service should have been done in a good architecture but, as the time is short, I want to reuse parts of code from the existing application which is not well designed.

I need to use a class (that have other dependent classes) and that class is in WEBINF/Classes/com.... and used by the existing webapp.

My first try was to add to the JAVA classpath the path to xxx/webapps/WEBINF/Classes where all the required packages are. I ran the full application and my new service was OK. The problem is that I've got Apache Tomcat unhappy telling it could not load struts -> ActionForm.

I've made then the following test: on a application version that runs OK, I've just added to the classpath in script used to launch the JVM the path to xxx/webapps/WEBINF/Classes. I started the application and I've got the problem directly. If I removethe reference to xxx/webapps/WEBINF/Classes then everything goes well.

1st question: Is the classpath used when starting-up the JVM inherited by catalina when is started via Catalina.start() in the same JVM instance?

2nd question: I have the feeling that if a class is in the JVM classpath and present in the xxx/webapps/WEBINF/Classes too then apache Tomcat is confused and it says it can't find anymore struts classes. Did you observed that? Any solution?

Do you have any othr solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here below the answer to my question :)

Once you feed Tomcat with classpath (don't forget is an embedded starting), then all dependent libs shall be fedded the same way. Don't expect Tomcat uses its class loader for finding them.
Another potential way would be to configure a shared lib path but I didn't lead to a working situation in my case.

Kind regards,

Vlad VALICA